# Which ram in TC387 chip can retain the original information after software reset

Tags: retention

I didn't find the instructions  in the chip manual

Here is the chip manual explains
Application Reset:
This reset leads to an initialization into a defined state of the complete application system with the following
parts: all peripherals, the CPUs and parts of the SCU.

Does it mean that the software reset will not clear ram?

Answer (score 0):

Software reset will cause the program to be executed from the first line. When the PC pointer jumps to the first line, all the parameter variables have not changed at this time, and the state just before the reset will be maintained until the initialization position of the variables begins to change to the set initialization value, and the value of flash will remain the last value. If a hardware reset occurs, the values of all registers will be in the initial state, and the value of flash will remain the last value.